# $E\times B$ drift in strongly nonuniform fields

Tags: classical-mechanics, electrostatics, conservation-laws, computational-physics, magnetostatics

Potential is defined as $\{\phi,\, 0,\, A,\, 0 \}$; fields are static and depend only on the axial coordinate $x$: $E_x=-\partial_x\phi$, $B_z=\partial_x A$. Charged particle moves in the $\{x,y\}$-plane, where $y$ is a direction of drift-motion.

There are two constants of motion:
$\frac{m}{2} \left(v_{x}^{2} + v_{y}^{2} - v_{x0}^{2} - v_{y0}^{2}\right) -e\phi $
and
$m \left(v_{y} - v_{y0}\right) - \frac{A e}{c} $, where $v_{x0}$ and $v_{y0}$ are velocities at given initial point $x_0$ (where $\phi\equiv0$ and $A\equiv0$).

We assume that $\phi$ and $A$ are monotonic. Thus, a solution for velocities can be expressed as
$$v_x = \pm\sqrt{- \frac{A^{2} e^{2}}{c^{2} m^{2}} - \frac{2 A e v_{y0}}{c m} + \frac{2 e \phi}{m} + v_{x0}^{2}}\\v_y = \frac{A e}{c m} + v_{y0}$$
And it works fine in the case of uniform fields. However, it gives multi-valued loops in some cases of nonuniform fields. Figures below show both the correct and incorrect examples. The only difference here is a selection of $x_0$.

So, the question is how to determine the incorrect branch of the solution without step-by-step calculation from $x_0$ to $x$?

In these examples: $\phi(x) = {\rm erf}(\exp(10x))-\phi_0$ and $A(x)=164\int (1-x^2)^2dx - A_0$, $v_{x0}=v_{y0}=0$, position of incorrect solution is around $x\approx-0.335$.

[image: Correct solution]

[image: Multi-valued solution]

The phase-loops are shown below for both solutions:

[image: Correct phase-loop]

[image: Multi-loop]